# 404 while pushing JS variables to PHP, calling a PHP function, getting result as a JSON string to JS and possibly failing while working with it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, mean

So I've found like gazillion of StackOverflow questions and answers to all the subtopics of my title. Linked them together and got 404. 
I am using MEAN stack to build simple API searching app.

This is the echo of 'together.php'(function is working just fine):

```
$variable1 = $_POST['JavaScriptButtonVariable1'];
$variable2 = $_POST['JavaScriptButtonVariable2'];
echo json_encode(inst_search(myfunction($variable1, $variable2)));
```

Here is the give part of my JSON object:

```
{"Target hashtag searched":"pizza","Additional keyword searched":"italia","Number of instagram submitters this session":20,"Total number of tags submitted":242,"Score of this hashtag\/keyword pair this session":6,"Date and time (YYYY\/MM\/DD HH:MM:SS)":"2015\/07\/23 09:34:55am","0":[{"Location":null,"Tags":["bandung","jakarta","pizzaitalia","pizza"]},{"Location":{"Location":"Catania","Area":"Catania","Region":"Provincia di Catania"},"Tags":["casa","famiglia","food","sicily","pizza
```

Keys interesting for me are: 'Number of instagram submitters this session', 'Total number of tags submitted', 'Score of this hashtag/keyword pair this session' and 'Date and time (YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS)', thus I am using [2],[3],[4] and [5] (visible in the code below). There is only one value assigned to those keys every time.

This is the part of the function in my 'global.js' file which calls the php file:

```
var parsedData = [];
var eins = $('#variable1').val();
var zwei = $('#variable2').val();
$.post
('together.php',{variable1:eins,variable2:zwei},function(omg)
    {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(omg);
    }
);
var php_no_sub = parsedData[2];
var php_tags_sub = parsedData[3];
var php_score = parsedData[4];
var php_datetime = parsedData[5];

  var newTag = 
    {
        'searchrecords': php_no_sub.val(),
        'tagsfound': php_tags_sub.val(),
        'datetime': php_score.val(),
        'score': php_datetime.val()
    }
```

Now, I simplified the code to the parts which may cause the problem, including the 404 error while calling and possibly my extreme inability to correctly construct JS objects from arrays extracted from JSON.

When clicking on the link http://localhost... my together.php gets downloaded, so it is definitely in the right directory.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/together.php
```

**Questions: Why is my console calling 404? Is the code for the array and the object written correctly?EDIT : How to allow POSTing to my php file by routing?**

PS: Here's the full text of my console error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/together.php 404 (Not  Found)x.ajaxTransport.x.support.cors.e.crossDomain.send @ jquery.min.js:6x.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:6x.each.x.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:6addTagAutoTogether @ global.js:190x.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:5x.event.add.y.handle @ jquery.min.js:5
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the full url for the post?

Comment: file:///C:/node/instagram/public/together.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.x.ajaxTransport.x.support.cors.e.crossDomain.send @ jquery.min.js:6x.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:6x.each.x.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:6addTagAutoTogether @ global.js:190x.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:5x.event.add.y.handle @ jquery.min.js:5
jquery.min.js:6 Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/node/instagram/public/together.php'.

Comment: That code certainly doesn't look like it's using the MEAN stack.

Comment: I am a newbie, putting everything up in global.js, simply because, as visible above, I cannot route properly. Is it what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking the link creates a `GET` request, but your code creates a `POST` message. Your servers API apparently doesn't know about any POST for that url, so it returns a 404. 
I don't know about the backend of your API, but perhaps you have to set a (`POST`)route first.

Comment: http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/

For now I have been following this guide, modified it so I can learn something else. There is a repository right there:
https://github.com/cwbuecheler/node-tutorial-2-restful-app

Any suggestions how I should set my POST route and where?

Comment: no, we don't even know what your server uses (you mention Node and PHP ?),  so that is impossible to answer.

Comment: I am using full end to end MEAN stack (I suppose it means Mongo server and Node server). Mr. Buecheler from the tutorial mentions that we should avoid putting everything in global.js, but rather place links in it to everything else. But in the first tutorial we just wrapped everything up in this file. The PHP is there just to get some info from the Instagram Search API, so I am passing two variables to it and want it to give the resulting JSON string back. Apart from all that and the fact that my files are exactly like in the github repository mentioned above, is there anything else?

Comment: can't help you here. I already answered your question. if you have new questions create a new topic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583896/creating-a-route-in-mean-stack-to-send-variables-to-php-file-and-get-a-result-to